# WordPress content not showing

Tags: wordpress

I added a new piece of code to my `header.php` now the content for my Pages aren't being shown.

In my `index.php` main tag i have this code

```
            <?php if(!is_home() || !is_front_page) { // dont display on home page

                    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                                the_content();
                                endwhile; else: ?>
                                <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
                                <?php endif;
                    } ?>
```

now since adding the code below to my `header.php`, the_content for my Pages aren't being displayed. e.g. About, Contact etc

```
<?php
            query_posts('cat=Gallery');
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            the_content();
            endwhile;
            ?>
```

The code in `header.php` is to fetch Posts of a specific category but now the content for my Pages aren't being displayed.  Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Can you post the full code so we can see it in context? I'm not an expert to advise in the use of it but, I always advise against while loops, also, if - endif isn't necessary, just wrap your statements properly in { }

Comment: It's because by calling `query_posts` you're altering the "main query". Adding `wp_reset_query‎()` after your header loop should restore the main query, but with the cost of a 2nd database call. A better way would be to use the WP_Query class intead of query_posts...

Comment: How do i replace the WP_Query class and what does that consist of doing?

Comment: WordPress [advice not to use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) `query_post()` to alter the main query, if you are trying to show different templates for galleries, I think pages with category _Gallery_ isn't a good approach, instead, you can use [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types), follow the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and let WordPress load the right template for you.

Comment: Actually, it is Posts with the category Gallery.  I just want to fetch these posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query_posts()` replaces the posts retrieved by WordPress - have a look at [the Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Try using `get_posts()` instead.

It might also be worth calling [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) after your header loop, which can help prevent unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I tried get_posts() but not working. This is what i did but the page content isn't showing. `<?php
  $posts = get_posts('category=Events');
  echo $posts;
  ?>`  Is that correct?  This is without adding `wp_reset_query()`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `setup_postdata()` must be called for each of the results of `get_posts()` in order to use functions that make use of `$post` global variables, like `the_content()` (and `wp_reset_postdata()` after the loop)

Comment: In case onetrickpony's answer didn't help, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698576/get-posts-doesnt-work-but-query-posts-does-wordpress) has an example